# Coffeescript cli: "unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Using the example at the [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#installation) web site, I'm trying to use the cli to convert some javascript files but am getting an "unexpected end of input" error. Their example looks like this:

```
coffee --compile --output lib/ src/
```

I've changed the parms etc and am calling this from the directory where the CS files are. This must be some sort of "operator error" but I'm not seeing it and none of the variations I've tried have helped (using absolute paths, changing param order, etc.). Running on OSX.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems.

1. switch the param order back so the source directory containing the `.coffee` files is last

`coffee --compile --output libjs/ lib/`

2. Run the above command straight in you terminal / console. From the screenshot it looks like you first ran `coffee` and then entered `--compile --output libjs/ lib/`.